# Save Canvas with image (REACT project)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, tagcanvas

I need to draw a canvas with a image and download the canvas as png.

1º click: save a empt image

2º error: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported"

I need to get a print of a video from a monitor cam (by the link).

I search solutions, but nothing work with me.

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function Home(){

  const ref = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const refLink = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>(null);

  function drawPhoto(){
    var image = new Image();
    if(ref.current){
      const canvas = ref.current.getContext('2d');

      image.src = 'https://s4.static.brasilescola.uol.com.br/be/2020/12/flor-de-maracuja.jpg';
      
      image.onload = function(){
        if(canvas){
          canvas.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function downloadBase64File(base64Data: string, fileName: string) {
    const downloadLink = refLink.current;
    if(downloadLink){
      downloadLink.href = base64Data;
      downloadLink.download = fileName;
      downloadLink.click();
    }
    
}

function saveCanvas() {
  if(ref.current){
    const d = ref.current.toDataURL('image/png');

    downloadBase64File(d, 'teste');
  }
}

function getScreenShot(){
  drawPhoto()
  saveCanvas()
}


  return(
    <div>
      <a ref={refLink}>
        <canvas id="video-cam" width="640" height="480" ref={ref}> </canvas>
      </a>
      <button type='button' onClick={() => getScreenShot()}> Print </button>
      <img id="main" width="640" height="480"  src='https://s4.static.brasilescola.uol.com.br/be/2020/12/flor-de-maracuja.jpg'/>
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

I try with fixed image.

I try 'document.createElement("a")'

I try img.crossOrigin="anonymous" and img.crossOrigin="http://localhost:3000/"  

And others solutions...